# Why were there no consequences for the losing party after this trial by combat?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, laws

In the novella *The Sworn Sword* (not the graphic novel) ...

> ... the Red Widow is accused of burning down Wat's Wood (or sending someone to do it). She wants to prove her innocence with a trial by battle. The Red Widow's champion loses the battle, which means she's found guilty of the crime, but still there are no consequences.

Why wasn't she punished?

Comment: She was; she had to marry Ser Eustace Osgrey (who became Lord of Coldmoat).

Answer (score 6):

Actually KutuluMike is mistaken when he says that Lady Webber was the accuser and Ser Eustace was the defendant.

#### Context

There were two main conflicts there:

1. The attack by Ser Bennis on peasants of Lady Webber.
2. The burning of Osgrey woods supposedly by Webber men at arms.

There was also another conflict, which basically started the aforementioned two conflicts but it was in the sidelines as a result of more immediate events:

1. Building of a dam on Chequey Water by the Webbers

#### The first dispute

Ser Duncan resolved the first issue by taking responsibility for Ser Bennis' offense and inflicting the same injury on himself as Ser Bennis inflicted on Lady Webber's peasant, thereby settling that score.

> The widow’s eyes went wide at the sight of naked steel. “What are you
> doing?” she said. “Have you lost yourwits ? There are a dozen
> crossbows trained on you.”
>
> “**You wanted blood for blood**.” He laid the dagger against his
> cheek. “**They told you wrong. It wasn’t Bennis cut that digger, it
> was me**.” He pressed the edge of the steel into his face, slashed
> downward.
>
> When he shook the blood off the blade, some spattered on her face.More
> freckles, he thought. “**There, the Red Widow has her due. A cheek for
> a cheek.**”
>
> “You are quite mad.” The smoke had filled her eyes with tears. “If you
> were better born, I’d marry you.”
> <sub>The Sworn Sword</sub>

#### The second dispute

After that, Duncan demanded that Lady Rohanne hand over the men who burned Ser Eustace's forest. Lady Webber had no intention of admitting that she was behind burning of the woods and even if someone among her men did it, she would not hand him over. She instead demanded that Ser Eustace withdraw his accusation that she burned his woods:

> “Give me the men who burned the wood.”
>
> “No one burned the wood,” she said, “but if some man of mine had done
> so, it must have been to please me. How could I give such a man to
> you?” She glanced back at her escort. “**It would be best if Ser
> Eustace were just to withdraw his accusation**.”
> <sub>The Sworn
> Sword</sub>

At that point, Duncan made it clear to her that no such thing would happen. Lady Webber then chose to defend herself in a trial by combat in case Ser Eustace refused to issue an apology to her for his vile accusation, thereby making her the defendant and Ser Eustace the accuser.

> “In that case, I must assert my innocence before the eyes of gods and
> men. Tell Ser Eustace that I demand an apology . . . or a trial. The
> choice is his.” She wheeled her horse about to ride back to her
> men.
> <sub>The Sworn Sword</sub>

#### Consequences

Later of course we know Duncan wins and Ser Lucas lost. The aftermath of the event is quoted below:

> “Ser Eustace asked the boy to attend him at the wedding feast. There
> was no one else on his side. It would have been discourteous for him
> to refuse.”
>
> “Wedding feast?” Dunk did not understand.
>
> “You would not know, of course. **Coldmoat and Standfast were
> reconciled after your battle**. Lady Rohanne begged leave of old Ser
> Eustace to cross his land and visit Addam’s grave, and he granted her
> that right. **She knelt before the blackberries and began to weep, and
> he was so moved that he went to comfort her. They spent the whole
> night talking of young Addam and my lady’s noble father**.
>
> Lord Wyman and Ser Eustace were fast friends, until the Blackfyre
> Rebellion. **His lordship and my lady were wed this morning,** by our
> good Septon Sefton. **Eustace Osgrey is the lord of Coldmoat**, and
> his chequy lion flies beside the Webber spider on every tower and
> wall.”
> <sub>The Sworn Sword</sub>

So as we can see, Ser Eustace and Lady Rohanne shared an intimate moment together, reminiscing about the loved ones they shared and had lost which were Eustace's son Addam and Lady Rohanne's father Lord Wyman.

It is implied by the fact that they chose to reconcile, that Ser Eustace forgave Lady Webber for burning his woods, therefore giving up the right to exact punishment on her. They went even beyond just reconciliation, they tied their houses together. By doing that, they resolved their original dispute too, the one about the dam.

So, it wasn't a trial by battle which had no consequences. It was a trial by battle which ended in reconciliation, which is a huge consequence.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I read that novella, but I think your plot summary in your spoiler is wrong.

As I recall, Lady Webber was the *accuser* in the confrontation with Dunk and Egg. One of her men had been wounded in a skirmish and she was bringing her army to get revenge. Duncan managed to talk her down into trial by combat between him (acting for Lord Osgrey, the defendant) and Lucas (acting for her, the accuser).

> When Duncan won, he effectively ended the feud between them and made peace. She wasn't found guilty of anything, rather, her accusation that Osgrey had dishonored her was settled in Osgrey's favor.

Comment: Confirmed [here](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Sworn_Sword).

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct. Dunk wounded his own cheek to pay blood with blood, then they talk about Wat's Wood and it's explicitly told that the trial by battle is about the wood. The wiki is misleading because Lady Webber wants an apology for being accused of burning Wat's Wood.

Comment: I'm talking about the novella not the graphic novel, maybe there is a difference.

Comment: @Chris Like I said, it's been a long time since I read it, but I'm pretty sure she burned Wat's Wood *because* one of Osgrey's men attacked one of her men at the start of the novel and she wants the apology to end her warpath. I'll go dig up the novella and find some citations, gimme some time :)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: I've had the novella before me when I wrote the question, therefore You could trust me. ;) Burning Wat's Wood was a reaction, but the trial is explicitly about that.

Comment: **1/3** You're both correct. But in this case, @Chris has the right of it. Lady Webber confronted Dunk and Ser Eustace (Ser Useless), accusing their man (Ser Bennis Brownwater) of hurting one of Lady Webber's. To which Dunk promptly takes blame and slashes his cheek as a sign of "blood for blood"

Comment: **2/3**  They then move on to the main accusation of the burning of Wat's Wood. Dunk accuses Lady Webber (or that she sent one of her men) of burning the wood. To which she denies and demands either a trial by the overlord (Lord  Rowan), or an apology for the accusations; but they both refuse, thereby leading to a Trial by Battle. Dunk VS. Ser Lucas Inchfield.

Comment: **3/3** SPOILERS: Dunk wins the Trial by Battle, but gets severely injured (as well as drowned and resuscitated in the Ironborn way). When he wakes from his Milk of the Poppy induced sleep, Maester Cerrick tells him that `“You would not know, of course. Coldmoat and Standfast were reconciled after your battle. ...  His lordship and my lady were
wed this morning, by our good Septon Sefton. Eustace Osgrey is the lord of Coldmoat, and his chequy
lion flies beside the Webber spider on every tower and wall.”"`

Comment: Chris is correct. Lady Webber was the defendant and Ser Eustace was the accuser. They simply chose to reconcile after the result of the trial, instead of Ser Eustace demanding reparations or punishments.